# change value of $scope in another controller in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i want to change $scope's values from another controller is code is follows:

this view is from app controller

```
<ion-item ng-show="before" menu-close ui-sref="app.login" href="">
              Login
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item ng-show="after" menu-close ui-sref="app.orders" href="">
              Orders
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item ng-show="after" menu-close ui-sref="app.exchange" href="">
              Exchange
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item ng-show="after" ng-click="logout();" menu-close href="">
              Logout
          </ion-item>
```

app contoller code:

```
if($rootScope.userId!=undefined){
        $scope.before=false;
        $scope.after=true;
    }
    else{

        $scope.before=true;
        $scope.after=false;
        $state.go('app.login');
    }
```

how can i get value and change it from login controller
thanks

Comment: Generally, you would use a service for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) to manage state in ionic 2 apps. It is RxJS powered state management for Angular applications, inspired by Redux.

If you don't want to use ngrx, you can use `events` or `$rootScope' to communicate between controller.

To use $rootScope in view:  Say if you have a `$rootScope.shared = {...}`, the can assign `$scope.sharedFromRoot = $rootScope.shared` and can access `sharedFromRoot` in the view.

Comment: i can user $rootScope but how can i view $rootScope's value in my view page ??